# Move Date to Nearest Sunday and End on Monday

Tags: sql-server

I want to write a store procedure to which i passed the two dates ranges and it shows the data between that ranges from `Order table`,but i want that my output date range move to nearest `Sunday` and end on `Saturday`.i-e if i pass it the starting date=`27-Mar-2014` which is `Thursday`,it shows data from date `23-Mar-2014` which is `Sunday`,and when i pass second date,i-e I pass `4-Apr-2014`,then it ending range become `7-Apr-2014` which is monday.In short whatever i pass the date range it make the starting date to `Sunday` of that week and ending date `Monday` of that week.Thanks

```
create procedure getdata 
@StartDate as Datetime, 
@EndDate as Datetime 
as 
begin 
select * from Table_8 
where Table_8.Date >= @StartDate 
and Table_8.Date   <= @EndDate 
order by Table_8.[Date] 
end  

declare @StartDate_temp as datetime  
declare @EndDate_temp as datetime  
set @StartDate_temp = DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, '2013-01-05')-1), '2013-01-05') 
set @EndDate_temp   = DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, '2013-01-13')), '2013-01-13') 
exec getdata @StartDate_temp,@EndDate_temp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply get the week start date from your 1st parameter and weekend date from 2nd parameter and pass them parameters to your select query inside your procedure. Something like this......

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_MyProc
 @Date_Param_1 VARCHAR(20),
 @Date_Param_2 VARCHAR(20)
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

 DECLARE @DateTime1 DATETIME, @DateTime2 DATETIME
       , @StartDate DATETIME, @EndDate DATETIME;

  SET @DateTime1 = CAST(@Date_Param_1 AS DATETIME)
  SET @DateTime2 = CAST(@Date_Param_2 AS DATETIME)

  SET @StartDate =  DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, @DateTime1)-1), @DateTime1) 

  SET @EndDate   = DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, @DateTime2)), @DateTime2) 

-- Now your Rest of the query 

 SELECT *
 FROM [Order]
 WHERE OrderDate >= @StartDate
  AND  OrderDate <= @EndDate

END
```

Comment: Thanks but when i use your code,it will show me all the data before and after of that range instead of breaking at Sunday(starting) and Monday(ending)

Comment: @MuhammadAli Post the definition of your procedure. this solution is 101% correct you must be doing something wrong somewhere else

Comment: You keep changing your requirements, In your question you were passing date as dd-MON-YYYY and now you are passing date as YYYY-MM-DD. Anyway I still I dont see anything wrong with your code, are you sure you data in your table which actually satisfy the conditions in where clause???

Answer (score 0):

The easy solution would be to use `weekday`, but that in turn depends on the specification of `DateFirst`.  To isolate this dependency (and perhaps introduce a linguistic one), the following uses `case`:

```
select blah
from foo
where OrderDate >= dateadd(day, (case datename(weekday, @StartDate)
                                   when 'Sunday' then 0
                                   when 'Monday' then 1
                                   when 'Tuesday' then 2
                                   when 'Wednesday' then 3
                                   when 'Thursday' then 4
                                   when 'Friday' then 5
                                   when 'Saturday' then 6
                                 end)
                          @StartDate
                   ) and
       OrderDate <= dateadd(day, (case datename(weekday, @EndDate)
                                   when 'Sunday' then 6
                                   when 'Monday' then 5
                                   when 'Tuesday' then 4
                                   when 'Wednesday' then 3
                                   when 'Thursday' then 2
                                   when 'Friday' then 1
                                   when 'Saturday' then 0
                                 end),
                            @EndDate)
                   )
```

Comment: when i use this code,it give me error that datename recieve two arguments,so what should i add there as a second argument?

Comment: @MuhammadAli . . . The `+` notation to add days is so handy that I often use it by default.  But, it doesn't work for `date`, only `datetime`.  And I fixed the argument problem too.